# Authentication header Vs Authorization header?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, header

I find this code in a Web project:

```
const customHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'clientId': env.apiKey,
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${authorization}`,
      'Authentication': `Bearer ${authentication}`
});
return this.http.get<UserInfo>(`${env.baseApi}/login`, { headers: customHeaders });
```

I know the header '`Authorization`' in Spring Security but what is the difference with the header '`Authentication`'? **For best practice, should we put both?**

Comment: I can't find the header `Authentication`, for example see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Comment: @dur, me no more, that's why I asked the question. I had searched before asking the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Authentication` is a custom header. Is it not a official header.